# В чем преимущество API для запроса данных из БД?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Предположим, мы имеем мобильное приложение, которое должно получать данные из БД. Никакой авторизации. Просто получение объекта по id и его описания. Можно ли создать пользователя БД, который имеет только права на чтение некоторых таблиц БД и все? Тогда мы можем коннектится к бд и делать прямые запросы, не тратя время на создание API. Чем я рискую?

Answer (score 3):

Коннект к БД это довольно ресурсоемкая штука, а клиентов если много - то гарантированно вы получите обвал системы. Чтобы избежать этого и требуется слой, который обеспечивает несколько коннектов к БД и много коннектов к клиентским устройствам.

Некоторые любят его называть сервером приложений, некоторые middle-tier, вы называете его API, но суть от этого не меняется.

Ну и на закуску, если вы дадите прямой доступ к БД, вы получите SQL injection. В свое время народ резвился так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

### Безопасность

Для любого диалекта SQL не составляет труда написать запрос, который положит сервер. Для этого необязательно даже иметь права на чтение чего угодно, запрос из нескольких десятков

```
cross join (select 1 as i union 2 union 3 union 4 union 5) dt
```

Положит почти что угодно.

Второй момент - у любой СУБД есть ограничение на число подключенных клиентов. Довести до DoS с этой стороны тоже весьма элементарно. Масштабировать же очень сложно.

И просто ошибки безопасности. Встречаются баги, требующие просто открытое соединение к базе для получения рута на сервере.

### Гибкость

Если у вас публична структура даже одной таблицы или одной хранимки - с этой таблицей/хранимкой вам придётся жить очень и очень долго. Изменить структуру будет равняться сломанной обратной совместимости.

Затем вдруг вам повезло и ваше приложение стало популярно. Кэширование не прикрутить, видимую структуру базы не поменять.

А вдруг решите переехать на другую СУБД? Ладно, это уже слишком маловероятная мысль. Хотя очень редко, но и такое встречается.

---

Проработайте структуру API. Сделайте backend топорно, но не отказывайтесь от возможности затем его при необходимости заменить. Элементарный middleware вида `метод_апи + параметры => SQL-запрос + плейсхолдеры` очевидно покроет ваши текущие задачи, очень быстро и просто расширяется и может быть легко заменён при необходимости без поломки обратной совместимости с приложением.

Answer (score 0):

По существу добавить к предыдущим ораторам уже нечего, но на этапе proof-of-concept подобные упрощения допустимы, это действительно экономит время, но подобные вольности в продакшне уже достаточно опасны.